# Mule outbound HTTP endpoints via proxy

Tags: java, proxy, mule

I have a mule application deployed on linux (RHEL 6) box which talks to twilio API and Gmail API. The server where the mule application is deployed has to go out via proxy.

I  have modified `/usr/local/mule-standalone-3.5.0/conf/wrapper.conf`  and added additional java property for proxy settings (using `wrapper.java.additional.4`)

and when I search the mule process, here is what I see

```
$ ps -ef | grep mule
root     12940 12938  0 Dec04 ?        00:04:24 java -Dmule.home=/usr/local/mule-standalone-3.5.0 -Dmule.base=/usr/local/mule-standalone-3.5.0 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=TRUE **-Dhttp.proxyHost=http://<proxy> -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=http://<proxy> -Dhttps.proxyPort=80**
```

I still am not able to hit the outbound HTTP/ HTTPS urls.

Is there a different way of setting outbound proxy in mule?

Answer (score 0):

Please try [configuring the proxy](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-ConfigurationReference) in the connector.